# Cordova plugin remove/add are taking very long

Tags: cordova

I have **cordova 8.0.0** and I'm using **cordova-android 7.1.**

Everytime I run a command like

```
cordova plugin remove ...
# or
cordova plugin add ...
```

The commands take 8+ minutes to end. 
I checked my network stats and I saw that node is downloading loads of things the whole time. Seems like it's fetching every plugin at every command.

Why is cordova doing that? It's slowing so much my development...

Answer (score 2):

So, I don't know why but I had some dependencies issues. The next time I ran `npm i ...` for another package, it took loads of time (as long as after every `cordova` command), and I got a message saying than more than one package has been updated.

Then the next cordova commands ran really faster.

So it seems that if you have some uninstalled npm packages in your `package.json` file, cordova 8.0.0 is downloading them at every command...

Comment: It's slow for me, too. But I don't understand how you fix it. Is there a way to avoid downloading them? I downgraded to 7.1.0 and it is still slow.

Comment: Using --no-fetch seems to speed it up for me but removal still takes forever.

Comment: Did you try to run `npm i` ?

Comment: Yes I have. I realized that running `npm i` repeatedly takes a long time, too. And then you know what the nofetch flag works for removal as well. And it's blazing fast! I am not sure exactly what it does though.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a known issue. As stated [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-fetch/issues/52) the only solution is to wait for Cordova 9 to be released. And it won't be until the end of the year at least...